# Concatenating same column values to single row using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a requirement to Concatenate same column values to single row using sql query.
Table A

```
TxnId   Sequence    Value
111        1          A
111        2         for
111        3         Apple
222        1         B-
222        2         Ball
333        1         C-Cat
```

Expected result

```
TxnId   Value
111      A for Apple
222      B- Ball
333      C-Cat
```

Please help. I need to concatenate the value based on TxnId and sequence

Comment: Have You tried to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

`Stuff()` function  with `xml` will help you

```
SELECT TxnId,
       Value = STUFF(
                    (
                        SELECT ' '+Value FROM <table>
                        WHERE TxnId = T.TxnId
                        ORDER BY Sequence FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('(text())[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM <table> T GROUP BY TxnId;
```

Result :

```
TxnId   Value
111     A for Apple
222     B- Ball 
333     C-Cat
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard SQL function cor this [`listagg`](http://modern-sql.com/feature/listagg), which is not supported by SQL Server yet. However, Since the latest release of SQL Server, it has got something similar: [`string_agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql).

It works along this line:

```
SELECT TxnId
     , string_agg(value, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Sequence)
  FROM ...
 GROUP BY TxnId
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XML Path for [group concatenation](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation).

**SQL Code**

```
declare @myt table (txnid int,[sequence] int , [value] nvarchar(50))
insert into @myt    
values
(111        ,1,         'A'    ),
(111        ,2,         'for'  ),
(111        ,3,         'Apple'),
(222        ,1,         'B-'   ),
(222        ,2,         'Ball' ),
(333        ,1,         'C-Cat')



SELECT txnid, [Value] = STUFF((SELECT N' ' + [Value] 
FROM @myt AS p2
WHERE p2.txnid = p.txnid 
ORDER BY [sequence]
FOR XML PATH(N'')), 1, 1, N'')
FROM @myt AS p
GROUP BY txnid
ORDER BY txnid;
```

**Result**

[image]